# Change app name without uploading new binary?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

Am I able to change my app name shown in App Store without uploading new binary and going though the whole submission process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to change your app's name, you have to create a new version. There is no other possibility.